# Swift : Terminating app with uncaught exception of NSExeption?

Tags: swift, xcode

Before you say "this is a repeat of a question", no. I have checked the question before and all it tells me is to check my outlets. All my outlets are correct and I'm not sure why I'm getting this error. Here's the error in detail :

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception     'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSTaggedPointerString objectForKeyedSubscript:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa00000000006e652'
*** First throw call stack:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ddf5d4b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010d85e21e objc_exception_throw + 48
2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010de65f04 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 132
3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010dd7b005 ___forwarding___ + 1013
4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010dd7ab88 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
5   Calc                                0x0000000108d00b37 -[MPCoreInstanceProvider appTransportSecuritySettings] + 284
6   Calc                                0x0000000108cc4147 +[MPAdServerURLBuilder queryParameterForAppTransportSecurity] + 76
7   Calc                                0x0000000108cc30d4 +[MPAdServerURLBuilder URLWithAdUnitID:keywords:location:versionParameterName:version:testing:desiredAssets:adSequence:] + 1674
8   Calc                                0x0000000108cc2a01 +[MPAdServerURLBuilder URLWithAdUnitID:keywords:location:versionParameterName:version:testing:desiredAssets:] + 173
9   Calc                                0x0000000108cc2920 +[MPAdServerURLBuilder URLWithAdUnitID:keywords:location:testing:] + 116
10  Calc                                0x0000000108cd3cde -[MPBannerAdManager loadAdWithURL:] + 470
11  Calc                                0x0000000108cc03a2 -[MPAdView loadAd] + 48
12  Calc                                0x000000010895aa1f _TFFC4Calc18MenuViewController11viewDidLoadFT_T_L_7loadAdsfT_T_ + 175
13  Calc                                0x0000000108957d18 _TFC4Calc18MenuViewController11viewDidLoadfT_T_ + 8104
14  Calc                                0x000000010895b632 _TToFC4Calc18MenuViewController11viewDidLoadfT_T_ + 34
15  UIKit                               0x00000001099cb8b1 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 1258
16  UIKit                               0x00000001099cbce4 -[UIViewController view] + 27
17  UIKit                               0x0000000109895405 -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 71
18  UIKit                               0x0000000109895b56 -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 293
19  UIKit                               0x00000001098a9469 -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 42
20  Calc                                0x0000000108c32264 _TFC4Calc11AppDelegate11applicationfTCSo13UIApplication29didFinishLaunchingWithOptionsGSqGVs10DictionaryVSC29UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKeyP____Sb + 5716
21  Calc                                0x0000000108c34674 _TToFC4Calc11AppDelegate11applicationfTCSo13UIApplication29didFinishLaunchingWithOptionsGSqGVs10DictionaryVSC29UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKeyP____Sb + 180
22  UIKit                               0x0000000109820312 -[UIApplication _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:] + 290
23  UIKit                               0x0000000109821c97 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 4236
24  UIKit                               0x000000010982803d -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1731
25  UIKit                               0x00000001098251bd -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 188
26  FrontBoardServices                  0x00000001160176cb __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 24
27  FrontBoardServices                  0x0000000116017544 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 189
28  FrontBoardServices                  0x00000001160178cd -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 45
29  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010dd9a761 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
30  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010dd7f98c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
31  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010dd7ee76 __CFRunLoopRun + 918
32  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010dd7e884 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 420
33  UIKit                               0x0000000109823a3a -[UIApplication _run] + 434
34  UIKit                               0x0000000109829bb8 UIApplicationMain + 159
35  Calc                                0x0000000108c4617f main + 111
36  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000110df668d start + 1
37  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Comment: this is a repeat of a question

Comment: Looks like the `Info.plist` of your app may not have a proper values for `NSAppTransportSecurity` or one of its children - [MPCoreInstanceProvider.m](https://github.com/mopub/mopub-ios-sdk/blob/master/MoPubSDK/Internal/MPCoreInstanceProvider.m)

Comment: Make that your answer, it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the `Info.plist` of your app may not have a proper values for `NSAppTransportSecurity` or one of its children.

Check out: [MPCoreInstanceProvider.m](https://github.com/mopub/mopub-ios-sdk/blob/master/MoPubSDK/Internal/MPCoreInstanceProvider.m).

"this is a repeat of a question" - next time look at your stack trace, it contains all the hints required:

- Close to the top you have the `-[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:]` which is throwing the exception (`objc_exception_throw` ...)

  - `doesNotRecognizeSelector` means that some code tried to invoke a method which is not available
  - which one? Look further above: `-[NSTaggedPointerString objectForKeyedSubscript:]`
  - so the method missing is `objectForKeyedSubscript:` which is what the Objective-C compiler generates for an expression like: `myObject[@"title"]`
  - it also tells you the class of the object the method is invoked on: `NSTaggedPointerString`, so some code tried to use `[]` on a plain string, which doesn't make much sense
- Next thing to check is who invoked that code: `-[MPCoreInstanceProvider appTransportSecuritySettings]` is the last regular code in the stack

  - so you DuckDuckGo `MPCoreInstanceProvider` and find [MPCoreInstanceProvider.m](https://github.com/mopub/mopub-ios-sdk/blob/master/MoPubSDK/Internal/MPCoreInstanceProvider.m)
  - which happens to have a `appTransportSecuritySettings` method
  - looking into the code it grabs a dictionary `NSDictionary *atsSettingsDictionary = [NSBundle mainBundle].infoDictionary[kMoPubAppTransportSecurityDictionaryKey];`
  - and then does a lot of `[]` operations on that dictionary and values of it
- Conclusion: One of the `[]` is hitting a string when it was expecting a dictionary.

Comment: You led me to the right path but all I had to do was change the name of App Transport Security Settings to App Transport Settings